# Porting of TwinCAT2 to TwinCTA3

Tags: plc, twincat, twincat-ads

I have a running project of twinCAT 2 (made for XP 32bit ) & Its working as required. Now I tried to port this project into TwinCAT3 (windows 10 64bit) for that->

1. I opened twinCAT 3 Created a new project.
2. Then add the existing project where I added  ".tsm" file of TwinCAT2.
3. Then I added the PLC file (which have the main program & GUI also)
4. Then all the mapping for input and output & also changed a few settings in twinCAT for the device.

In the end, I build the program without having any errors.
Then finally I ran the TwinCAT3 program....

**The problem I'm facing**

1. If I'm clicking the RUN button TwinCAT3 is getting hanged (don't  know the maybe time-related file is creating issue)
2. I'm not able to see data on GUI (Maybe GUI file not linked with the main program).

Please let me know if any solution you guys have.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Porting TwinCAT2 plc project with a visualization to TC3 is sometimes a little tricky. You can try to just import the visualization pictures into the plc and let the engineering do the rest automatically (bind libs etc.). Or check the lib-versions of the visu libs manually. Or check the visualization profile in the plc-project properties. In both cases the slogan is "latest greatest" in this scope.
Is the connection to other data from the target also lost? E.g. the current cpu-usage of the cores? If yes, you have a other problem. Mostly endless loop.